# Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage??' to type 'UIImage?' Swift 5

Tags: xcode, swift5

Why does swift(Xcode) requires a "!!" double exclamation mark after using  `randomElement()` to an `UIImage` array, it by itself gives me an error.

Example:

```
someView1.image = viewArray.randomElement()   // right here it tells me to put !!
```

after putting the "!!" at the end everything works fine. Why?

Comment: Show your code, including declarations.

Comment: Please learn about Optionals. You'll face endless frustrations and questions trying to power through without understanding them. They're so fundamental, in fact, that the page that covers them in The Swift Programming Language (TSPL) is literally called [the basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `viewArray` is *not* an array of UIImage. It is an array of *Optional* UIImage. Well, calling `randomElement()` itself adds a level of Optionality, because the array itself might be empty. Thus you get an Optional wrapping an Optional wrapping a UIImage.

Simple solution: say

```
viewArray.compactMap {$0}.randomElement()
```

That unwraps the Optionals in the array. Now `randomElement` yields an Optional. You will still need to unwrap it if you want a UIImage, but at least there will be only one level to unwrap.

Comment: Actually there is some evidence that `viewArray` itself might contain double wrapped Optionals and that `randomElement` is yielding a triple wrapped Optional. But you have given no information so it's impossible to tell from here.